# Dealing with antisemitism at a networking event

Tags: professionalism, networking

I was at a holiday networking mixer and was talking with a middle eastern man about unrelated business talk, a couple people floated in, and the conversation turned to global economic events, and then the Israel-Hamas conflict. Someone asked if anyone had a personal connection to Israel (likely in an attempt to avoid the subsequent sequence of events), and I identified myself and my family as Jewish, with friends who currently live in Israel.

Shortly thereafter, he was asked if he thought Israel had a right to exist and he answered "no".

I froze and said nothing for the next 2 minutes, unable to believe he had just said that to a Jew he just met at a professional event in front of multiple people. I was balancing calling him out for antisemitism vs walking away and ultimately decided to walk away. After the fact, I regretted not standing up to it.

What could I have said to defend myself, my family, and my people, while remaining professional in front of a couple other people?

Comment: Context: this networking mixer, in what country did it take place?

Comment: What did you do about anti-semitism before?

Answer (score 12):

You probably did the best thing by letting the matter rest.

A stranger to you was explicitly asked (by whom, is unclear) "if he thought Israel had a right to exist", and said "no".

Without more, most people would reject that this utterance on geopolitics is an "anti-semitic attack" upon you. It is no more politically extreme an expression than rejecting the right to exist for "British India" or "French Indo-China", or of course, "apartheid South Africa" - all of which have been rejected and turned over in decades gone by.

It's important to recognise that people have a variety of reasons to reject Israel which do not originate in its mere association with, or claimed representation of, Jewish people generally.

You can of course have and express your own strong political views, and challenge the logic or ethics of those views you do not like, but whether you want to use a "networking event" for this purpose is a question only you could answer.

Comment: Massively naive to equate the call for the destruction of Israel with the abolishing of "British India". When people talk about the destruction of Israel, they mean expelling or killing the Jewish inhabitants of the area, not granting the area independence from a foreign power.

Comment: @DJClayworth, Israel has an explicit policy of disproportionate brutality towards the civilian population (well known as counter-productive because of its liability to produce extreme politics), and promoted Hamas so as to create an opponent seemingly too unreasonable to negotiate with, so it shouldn't be surprising that they generate rhetoric from the Palestinians - Israel connives to produce whatever rhetoric is necessary to give a veneer of justification to their own sectarian intransigence.

Comment: I don't disagree with you. Both sides are locked in a cycle of aggression that is very hard to break out of. But my comment above still stands.

Comment: @DJClayworth, indeed but Israel has the facilities and bureaucracy of a conventional state available, backed by others like the US, and it's not reasonable to suggest their actions and reactions are on an equal footing with that of loosely organised militants. It's like going into a school and finding teachers and pupils brandishing knives and killing each other - you wouldn't seriously believe that the regime was faultless and they were just dealing with an unusually tough intake of children. The only credible explanation would be that the state was doing *something* seriously wrong.

Comment: But what if the students really were bringing in knives and trying to stab the teachers on a regular basis? Would the teachers be unjustified in getting the students thrown out of the school? What would normally happen of course is that overwhelming force would be brought in (a SWAT team) and then the behaviour of each side would be investigated and addressed.

Comment: @Steve I guess its relevant, there was a lot more than a simple quiet no, he excitedly declared it. "No! Israel does not (*shakes head no once with some force*) have a right to exist"

Comment: @DJClayworth, in the analogy I'm imagining, the pupils drawn from the local area really are threatening and murderous towards teachers. But no person seriously thinks that such things just happen from time to time in a well-run school drawing from a well-run community - it's always symptomatic of broader maladministration by the state. Where you have a touch of this problem in the USA, with school shootings, SWAT teams have not pacified. Yet in well-run countries, even those with popular gun-ownership, such shootings are unheard of.

Comment: @hedgedandlevered, I already imagined it would have been a "no" said firmly, not meekly.

Comment: I don't deny Israeli culpability. But laying all the blame on Israel ( the teachers in your analogy) is also wrong. Either side denying the other's right to exist makes the situation worse.

Comment: @DJClayworth, the Palestinians are reacting with violence against a mixture of expropriation and brutal concentration-camping. Zionist politics however have always been the cause of this, not the result of it. That is, the sustenance for that extreme sectarian politics has always been subsidy and enabling by Western liberals (as with Biden currently), not the question of how the Palestinians behave in reaction to that politics. I struggle to find even the most superficial analysis in which Zionist tenets arise from the way Palestinians have behaved now or historically.

Comment: With the Middle East, it's always a question of how far back you go. Palestinian apologists start with Israel's expulsion of the Palestinians. Israelis start with the 1948 war and the attempt by the Arab nations to destroy Israel and kill or expel all Jews from the region. Or you can go further back. Go back 200 years if you like. Everybody says "but they started it".

Comment: @DJClayworth, I think living memory is sufficient in general. Most Gazans are not fighting 1948 all over again, they're reacting to the current conditions and the periodic brutalisations which Israel inflicts. Meanwhile, Israel has its Zionist agenda in which Palestinians are collateral victims but not the main focus, and support for that agenda is rooted in the current functions Israel performs for various interests. The biblical stuff is just hokum.

Comment: I hear plenty of people talking about 1948. Of course the other problem is that the rocket attacks and the terrorist massacres against Israel are not in general being done by Palestinians, they are being done by outside groups with an agenda who don't actually care what happens to the Palestinians.

Comment: @DJClayworth, I hear plenty talking about biblical exile too - even those who are avowedly secular! It's all guff in terms of what really drives people. I agree there are wider forces backing the Palestinians - mostly opponents of the US. That's an aspect of the conflict that shouldn't be neglected - the US backs Israel for its own reasons, and others then oppose Israel because it does US bidding in the region. Neither of these forces correspond to what drives the Israelis and Palestinians themselves.

Comment: Hamas has >50% support in Gaza, its their effective government. They have a goal: Take all israeli land and expel the current property owners. There was a cease fire in place October 6. Even if you think Israel shouldn't have gotten the land in 1948, taking it to the present day of "Israel doesn't have a right to exist" means "others should have it now" which means forcing israelis out of their homes with threats of violence. Thats not "Either side denying the other's right to exist", thats only Hamas denying Israel. Israel kicked their own citizens out of Gaza to give it away.

Answer (score 8):

First, we need to frame the problem correctly. You've said:

> Shortly thereafter, he was asked if he thought Israel had a right to exist and he answered "no".

You are also adding some context and try to interpret it as such:

> Someone asked if anyone had a personal connection to Israel (likely in an attempt to avoid the subsequent sequence of events)

But again, this is your guess at someone's intention, where it as likely could've been someone wanting to express sympathies if they were, and avoid unpleasant topics with a wide berth.

That's not antisemitism.

Israel is an independent nation, and just because it's population is majority Jewish, verbal "attacks" on a nation are not attacks on it's population, unless it stems from it. Here it's a simple statement on the Nation, not the Jewish people, and it's important that people learn to dissociate the two, as critique of a country, governments and all other entities like that is perfectly valid and fine.

Just like it's fine to say UK should fall apart, this isn't attack of the English, or Scottish or Welsh or Irish people, it's critique of the UK country for an easy example.

> What could I have said to defend myself, my family, and my people, while remaining professional in front of a couple other people?

With the above in mind, trying to turn this into issue of antisemitism on the spot is not something I would recommend, as it just simply doesn't seem to be one. What you should do instead is to act like you would whenever someone says something you consider utterly stupid at a professional event - for me that's to walk away to another conversation circle and make a mental note to give that persona a wide berth in the future.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150351/discussion-on-answer-by-aida-paul-dealing-with-antisemitism-at-a-networking-even); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 7):

I Umm'd and aaahh'd about answering this.

So to start with, so you know the perspective I'm coming from: Tomorrow the IDF could affix bayonets and pull out the Flamethrowers and I'd still consider that to be a 'Measured and proportional response'.

In terms of Workplace and professionalism though - here's another way of thinking about your question:

"I've wandered into a Minefield, how do I get out?"

The learning here is to see the Minefield in future and not walk into it.

It clearly is, for you, a bit of a sticking point that you failed to rebuff this statement - and I'd almost say that considering the topic, you were already so far into the realms of 'inappropriate work conversations' that any attempt at further professionalism is kinda moot.

That said - probably the best answer would be a question and a statement:

"What do you mean by your answer? My interpretation of that statement is that you want to violently remove people like me from their country - could you clarify? Because if that is what you mean, I can no longer interact with someone who wants my friends and family killed for their beliefs"

It's clunky - and as I said - if you've gotten to this point, you are so far off the reservation it's almost irrelevant - you can't get much more unprofessional at this point - but seeking a clarification (they may not mean it in terms of how certain H organizations mean it) would be the best option - since if they mean something different (and to be clear - I agree with you, they probably didn't) to articulate it.

That all said - the learning you should take away from this is the classic line from the movie 'War Games':

**The only winning move is not to play**

Answer (score 5):

There are two issues here, discussing polarizing issues at a networking event, and your freezing.

A better response might have been to deflect the conversation before it got to that stage. "We can all agree that the situation is tragic. But let's not talk about issues that possibly can be points of disagreement while we are at this event." If he persists in talking about the conflict, then walk away because that is contrary to the purpose of a holiday networking event.

Freezing in the face of danger is one thing that some people do. Your freezing is possibly something that a professional could help you with. It is a matter of coming up with responses so that you feel that you have the power to respond.

Comment: Not responding in situations like this is absolutely normal and very probably the best response. I don't think any kind of "professional help" is necessary.

Comment: @DJClayworth I take the comment on the professional help as addressing the "I froze" comment from the OP.  The OP did not respond because he chose not to, but because he was paralyzed, and was unable to - yet still desired to respond.   Getting past this sort of issue requires self inspection, preparedness and understanding - which are all the sorts of things that professional help could assist with.

Comment: Maybe. I've been in such a position and not responded because I was uncertain of a good response. Frequently, on reflection, I've realized that not responding was better than saying what it was that came to my mind first. But people are different.

Comment: "froze" probably suggested I was unable to respond despite knowing. Poor wording on my part, though the next sentence (and the fact I am posing this question at all) does clarify that that was not the case, and indeed, I could not decide.

Comment: @hedgedandlevered IMHO not be able to decide is semantically the same as freezing.

Answer (score 5):

If you're in a professional context and someone says something that you find objectionable, there are several different approaches that you can take:

- You can ignore it and continue the conversation (possibly steering it into safer territory).
- You can find an excuse to leave the conversation, and either move to a different group or leave the event.
- You can challenge them on what they said.

Which of these is the most "professional" will depend hugely on exactly what they said, the context of the event, your relationship with the individual, and crucially on your ability to have a *calm and measured* debate on the topic.

If you don't feel that you are likely to be able to do that (which is often the case if it's a subject that you feel very strongly about), then you should avoid getting into an argument with them - because it's very easy to end up acting unprofessionally if that happens, and you have very little to gain from doing so.

This is especially true for topics that are very controversial, or that end up quickly devolving into semantic debates (as you can see in some of the comments here) because the two sides meaning different things with the same words, and can't agree on a common language. If if people have been drinking, because that's rarely a catalyst for a constructive and intelligent discussion.

And after the fact, you can decide whether you want to take it any further - for instance if they work for your company then you might want to make a complaint against them. If it's someone from another company, then you might take that into consideration when deciding who to work with in future. And if it's someone you're never going to see again, then you can just move on with your life.

Sometimes your job will bring you into contact with people who you strongly dislike, or who's views your profoundly disagree with - and if that keeps happening, you may need to reconsider whether the organisation that you're working for is a good fit for you. But you need to pick your battles and decide when it's worth having that argument and when it's worth just walking away.

Answer (score 2):

I started to write about the multiple misunderstandings in this question about what "semitic" means, what "antisemitic" means, and the distinction between a people, a government, and a country... but really, that's all orthogonal to the question.

If someone says something you think others are likely to find offensive, you need to make a judgement call about whether you actually know enough to make that decision, and about whether the context calls for walking away (with or without saying why), changing the topic, or challenging. All three are justifiable depending on the exact statement and situation, and without being there and knowing all those factors we can't tell you which would have been most appropriate, nor how best to express it.

It's also worth noting that if you're trying to network for career purposes, you may want to avoid politically-related topics generally. They are much more likely to hurt that goal than help it. Remember why you are talking to this person in the first place, and that you don't have to like people to work effectively with them.

Answer (score -2):

> while remaining professional

It's very simple, you don't tell people you're semitic. If you paint a target on yourself you can expect people to take a shot at it.

Comment: I don't think that applies to this question, and I'm not convinced it's good advice generally. The Palestinians are also a semitic people, and the target of opportunity was a country rather than a people. I grant that if you say you're _Israeli_ you have to expect to hear some complaints about the country's history and current behavior (ditto for any other country, explicitly including my own), but that's a different question. Not all Jews are fond of Israel, and there are antisemites who are supporters of Israel as a place the Jews "should go back to."

Comment: Music cue: "Waiting For The Worms", Pink Floyd

Comment: @keshlam I'm very familiar with bigotism, it's always best just not to make yourself a target unless you want to for some reason. And best not to give potentially controversial information to strangers unless you're prepared for whatever might happen. I have no opinion and little interest on the current conflict.

Comment: My objection is specifically to "always".  That depends on your priorities. There is what's safest at the moment, what's most productive for the longer term in dealing with this individual, and what's best for the group... and in this case multiple groups that don't fully overlap. Staying invisible/closeted/silent fits the first goal. Trying to educate,  when it can be matter of fact vs. bias, fits the last.  It's a continuous spectrum; pick the trade-off that is appropriate for the place, time, context and people. "Absolutes are inherently false." Including that one.

Comment: @keshlam ok I understand that and you're correct, but you misunderstand my comment, I qualified the 'always' with 'unless' both times I used it.

Comment: If you update the actual _answer_ with that "unless", and acknowledge that it often *ISN'T* that simple, then I think we're in agreement. Otherwise the answer itself will be misunderstood... or if I'm understanding it correctly, I continue to disagree.

Comment: @keshlam just you misunderstanding it, I'm fine with the downvote though, have a good day.